# Oauth2 Spring implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

Im am new in Spring. I would like use Oauth2 with Spring Security.
This is my app:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http

                    .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
                            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"),
                            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/beans")
                    ))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
                throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("id");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                                  "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("id")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
                    .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "trust").resourceIds("id")
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
                    .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds("id")
                    .secret("secret");
        } 
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
                               GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
                    .roles("USER").and().withUser("admin").password("password")
                    .roles("USER");
        }   
    }  
}
```

I want to use password grant authentication. Unfortunately when I run such command:

```
curl -u my-client-with-secret: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password&username=user&password=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&client_secret=secret
```

the response is:

```
{"timestamp":1477484999849,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/oauth/token"}
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the curl Request a little. Please put the credentials from the client in front of the Request and append the user credentials as parameters:

```
curl my-client-with-secret:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password
```